# Is there anyway to mask an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input field and I want to apply auto slashing on it. Something like MM/YY.

For example, if someone types MM (05) it should automatically add a slash to separate month from the year, and if someone removes the second number the slash should be removed.

Is it possible via CSS? Can someone help me with how to do it?

```html
<input type="number">
```

Comment: number of js script available, just google it.

Comment: Is it possible via CSS 

Comment: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ use Jquery mask plugin

Comment: @SureshKamrushi I have tried to search it all the scripts are date based.

Comment: @Yahiya This plugin also comes with DD/MM/YY. I want to only use it for MM/YY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not recommending you use this technique. Instead of these use some external libraries

```js
$("#masked").on("change paste keyup", function() {
  let inputValue = $(this).val();
  if (inputValue.split("/")[0] > 12) {
    $(this).val(12);
  }
});

$("#masked").mask("00/00");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>Masked Input Plugin as MM/YY.</h3>
  <table border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="masked" type="text" value="" placeholder="MM/YY" data-mask="00/00"
            data-mask-clearifnotmatch="true"/>
        </td>
        <td>typing 0221 but getting 02/21</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks for saving me. Can it also identify that there are 12 months only? and not letting add user 15/20? Also, can I restrict years, not in the backdate?

Comment: @Robinhood See the edit I am not recommending you to use this technique. Why can't you any DateTime library for this input?

Comment: This is because I don't need DD and that's what I see is the problem in the edited code. You now made it as a DD/MM input field, whereas before it was MM/YY input field. I requested you to just put a check on the month MM and leave YY as it is, instead what you have done is changed MM to DD and YY to MM. So there's no YY now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<form action="">

  <div>
    <label for="cc">Expiration Date</label>
    <!-- Set via HTML -->
    <input id="cc" type="text" placeholder="MM/YY" class="masked" pattern="(1[0-2]|0[1-9])\/(1[5-9]|2\d)" data-valid-example="05/18"/>
  </div>

</form>

<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/masking-input.js" data-autoinit="true"></script>

</html>
```